# HLSL Internal Error: L-Value Expected when multiplying int/dword (weird)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, direct3d, hlsl, xor

Ok to start off, I'm using Managed DirectX and shader model 3.0, and I'm trying to create a software implementation of bitwise operators.  So for XOR, it looks like this:

```
dword Xor(dword x, dword y)
{
  dword result=0, mult=1;
  while (x > 0 || y > 0)
  {
    result += (x%2 != y%2) * mult;
    x /= 2;
    y /= 2;
    mult *= 2; //internal error: l-value expected
  }
}
```

After a lot of experimenting and trying to trick the compiler, I arrived at the following conclusion: **anything that results in the equivalent of a locally declared integer being multiplied by an integer is not allowed by the compiler.**  Which is really weird.  I can multiply x or y (parameters) by 2 but not mult.  I can't add it to itself, or divide by 0.5, or anything else like that.

Can anyone come up with an explanation for this?  On a side note, does anyone know a better implementation of Xor (couldn't find one on Google).  Bit-shifts are not available.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: why are you trying to create a software implementation of XOR? Why not just use the operator?

Comment: Have you looked at `mul`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509628(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Shader model 3 doesn't support bitwise operators (and, or, xor) or bit-shift operators.  I tried "mult = mul(mult, 2);" and still get the same error.  Don't know why the compiler hates it so much - I'm getting by for now with mult being a float, but I'm still wondering why the error occurs.

Comment: Which HLSL compiler are you using exactly?

Comment: Visual C# 2008 Express Managed DirectX libraries - loading .fx file and compiling at runtime.  Still never found a solution to this.